# moving from Debian/Ubuntu to CentOS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, centos

Hey does anyone have any good resources for a sysadmin who's moving from a Debian/Ubuntu system to CentOS?

Tutorials/HowTo's along the line of "I'm already a sysadmin on a Debian system,  and now I have to support a CentOS system as well."

Comment: doesn't this question belong to superuser.com?

Comment: There are other stackexchange sites for this sort of question

Comment: There's a whole site over at ServerFault.com specifically for server administrators. StackOverflow is specifically for programming-oriented questions.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, CentOS is essentially Fedora/RedHat, so seek support on those operating system.

I suggest http://fedoraforum.org and http://linuxquestions.org. LinuxQuestions.org is pretty Fedora-biased, but you could also ask questions there about CentOS.

Comment: Something that I have found useful on CentOS is EPEL http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL which stands for Extra Packages to Enterprise Linux. This is useful for getting Fedora packages which haven't (yet) been incorporated into CentOS.

Comment: Actually CentOS is basically Redhat Enterprise Linux. Not Fedora. When you are looking for specific help, packages, etc. RHEL and Fedora are not always the same. That said, there is plenty of help online for both RHEL and CentOS.